# Why my module API communication is blocked by my Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.4.3

My ERP module connects via API and sends 1k of the product's data when there are changes from my ERP side.
In the logs, I just see the message below and my stock hasn't been updated.

```
Web API is unable to process.
```

I think it's something new in Magento 2.4 since I just updated from Magento 2.3 and the issue started. How could I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because in the new Magento versions 2.4.3 and 2.3.7-p1 we have built-in Web API limits.

REST requests containing inputs representing a list of entities are limited to a **default maximum of 20 entities** to avoid DDoS attacks.

**I recommend spreading the requests in small requests and not have a huge amount of data in one request or a short period of time instead of disabling or increase the built-in API limits.**

#### How to disable limits

To disable the input limits on the REST API request, apply one of the following patches (depending on your version):

[MC-43048__set_rate_limits__2.3.7-p1.patch.zip](https://github.com/magento/knowledge-base/blob/main/src/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/assets/MC-43048__set_rate_limits__2.3.7-p1.patch.zip?raw=true)

[MC-43048__set_rate_limits__2.4.3.patch.zip](https://github.com/magento/knowledge-base/blob/main/src/troubleshooting/known-issues-patches-attached/assets/MC-43048__set_rate_limits__2.4.3.patch.zip?raw=true)

Reference [here](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/4406893342093) and [API security](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/api-security.html#rate-limiting).